# Invalid Client Id

Tags: apex, oauth2, oauth

Need to resolve some issue about the code which i have written. This is the error code:

> ```
> {"error":"invalid_client_id","error_description":"client identifier invalid"}
> ```

remote site setting:

```
https://vineet.cs18.my.salesforce.com/oauth2/services/token
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="accesstokenrest" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:commandbutton value="send http request" action="{!getaccesstoken}"/>

        {!showres}

        </apex:pageblock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex

```
public class accesstokenrest {
    public static string showres{set;get;}
    public static void getaccesstoken(){
        String clientId = '3MVG98RqVesxRgQ6mLzJ3Ah6LwMl7XWvdLirzijsSeEQo9yaJE1vVWrV.RLLGtLAzjTZWV0l9Y4DezE_VPWY5';
        String clientSecret = '9086754825672118897';
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&username="vsrivastava@logi.com"&password="sunny890"';

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');


    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('--------'+res.getBody());

    showres = res.getBody();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
  String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username=vsrivastava@logi.com&password=sunny890';
```

An example of code is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/07/using-apex-to-integrate-salesforce.html)